# ColdFusion cfselect binding not working on production server

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfform, cfselect

I have a few related selects that work perfectly on a testing server with very loose security (basically just a simple default install of CF 10).

I have tried to implement the CF 10 lockdown guide on the production server and all seems well, except that related select don't work. That is, the first select in the chain doesn't populate and therefore, none of the related selects populate either.

I even recreated Ben Forta's art media example: perfect on the testing server, no triggering in production.

All other CFC functions seem to work: SELECT and INSERT queries are just fine. Only CFSELECTs with bindings are hosed. I pretty sure that the problem is a server configuration. The same pages worked just fine on our old CF 9 box. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: You say it "doesn't work" - what error message(s) do you get? Can you post the configuration details? The more details you can provide the better the community can help you.

Comment: The dropdowns are not populated by the CFC. No errors are produced. The server is a 2008R2 install. Is there a good way to share IIS and/or CF configuration details here?

Comment: Check your browser's JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: I bet you ARE getting Javascript error(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice to you would be to NOT use cfselect or any other UI stuff in ColdFsuion - It only causes more headaches than it gets rid of.

That being said, if you followed the lockdown guide, you should have limited access to the CFIDE directory - which is needed for any of the ColdFusion UI stuff. There is an option in CF Admin to use a 'custom' path for the scripts ColdFusion uses - it is on the main `Settings` page. Set this value and create a virtual directory in IIS with the same name pointing to the `{cfroot}CFIDE/scripts` directory.

Comment: I'd've upvoted twice if I could: once for "My advice to you would be to NOT use cfselect or any other UI stuff in ColdFusion", and once for the rest of the answer.